# I'm looking for theorems regarding the eigenvalue spectra of contracted tensors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensors

During my research I was tasked by my supervisor to find a mathematical theorem that he was told exists by a fellow on a conference. I only know what it can be applied to but not exactly what the theorem precisely states, that's why I couldn't find anything and decided to look for help here.

What I'm looking for is:

Suppose we have a 4-dimensional matrix $M_{abcd}$ and I contract it in two different ways,
$A_{ij} = \sum_{a}M_{ijaa}$ and
$B_{ij} = \sum_{a}M_{aaij}$.
Now there is supposed to be a mathematical theorem that states that the dominant parts of the eigenvalue spectra of $A$ and $B$ are approximately equal.

I don't know what dominant and approximately equal mean in this case.
If you know of a theorem that might help me going further or can help me what to look for I'd be very grateful.

For now I only found theorems that are inequalities where differences of eigenvalues are smaller than some Matrix norms, but I don't think that this is what that scientist on the conference thought of.

Answer (score 0):

The hypothetical theorem looks very strange to me.

The only condition on eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ is that their sums must be the same (these sums are the traces of $A$ and $B$ and $\sum_b A_{bb}=\sum_a \sum_b T_{bbaa}=\sum_a B_{aa}$).

Indeed, let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices such that $\operatorname{Tr} A=\operatorname{Tr} B = s$. Take $T = \frac{1}{s} A \otimes B$, that is, $T_{ijkl} = \frac{1}{s} A_{ij} B_{kl}$. It is easy to see that $\sum_{a} T_{ijaa}=A_{ij}$ and $\sum_aT_{aaij}=B_{ij}$, so you can get two arbitrary matrices from the construction in question, as long as their traces are the same.